# how to add 2 timestamp column in sql where in 1 is current time and the other is current time+30minutes?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| current time        | expiry time         |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 10:10:10            | 10:30:10            |
| 23:40:10            | 00:10:10            |
| 13:10:10            | 13:40:10            |
| 05:10:00            | 05:40:00            |
|                     |                     |
|                     |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

There's another column in the table which is id and x column. basically the 2 timestamp is updated when a value is sent to x column. One is current time and the other is current time but +30 mins

I'm using MariaDB, and php the value is from a sensor.

```
if ($value == $row['end_at']){
    echo "XXX";
    $today = date("H:i:s");  
    $up = date("H:i:s", strtotime("+30 minutes"));
    $reg= "insert into table (current time+30mins) values ('$up')";
} else if  {

}
```

tried doing this but it ended up constantly updating the db each second.

updated another idea I've thought about is adding another column timestamp with different timezone i.e current time: GMT +8 expiry time: GMT+:8:30 is this plausible? and how do i do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which database you are using and what is the expected output?

Comment: With which language you are using sql and if you are using javascript then use moment.js add() for this.

Comment: updated another thought I've thought about is adding another column timestamp with different timezone i.e 

current time: GMT +8
expiry time: GMT+:8:30 is this plausible?

Comment: If they are _always_ 30 minutes apart; don't store it, just compute it on the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Your inserts should look like:

```
insert into t (x, id, current_time, expiry_time)
    values (?, ?, now(), now() + interval 30 minute);
```

Updates should look like:

```
update t
    set x = ?,
       current_time = now(),
       expiry_time = now() + interval 30 minute
    where id = ?;
```

The `?` are parameter placeholders for passing values into a query.